# Power BI - LinkedIn Ads connector

Tags: connection, powerbi

I would like to load LinkedIn Ads data into my Power BI report.

Are there any easy approach for accessing the data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

there are few options to connect Linkedin ads to Power bi:

1- Downloading the csv files and importing to Power bi.

2- Creating an app in Developper.linkedin.Com, and getting the an API URL.
Then in Power bi you press on Get data -> from web and then add your API URL in the box that appears.

3- This is probably the easiest option which is to use a third-party connector, but you will still need to create an app in Developper.linkedin.com, and use your client's id and client's secret key to be able to access your data.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that you need to write or a custom connector by following the docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/samples/trippin/readme

Or you need to write in M your custom code for accessing the API:

```
    let
    GetAccessToken = 
        let 
            TokenEndpointUrl = #"TokenEndpoint" &  "?client_id=" & #"AppID" & "&client_secret=" & #"AppSecret" & "&grant_type=client_credentials",
            TokenRequestResult = Json.Document(Web.Contents(TokenEndpointUrl)),
            AccessToken = TokenRequestResult[access_token]
        in 
            AccessToken,

    GetData = (Url)  => 
        let 
            FinalResult = if Url = ""
                then 
                    {}
                else 
                    let
                        Result = Json.Document(Web.Contents(Url,[
                            Query=[
                                date_preset="lifetime",
                                level="ad",
                                fields="impressions,spend,account_id,account_name,campaign_id,campaign_name,adset_id,adset_name,ad_id,ad_name",
                                time_increment="monthly"]
                        ])),
                        NextUrl = Record.FieldOrDefault(Result[paging],"next",""),
                        CombinedData = Result[data] & @GetData(NextUrl)
                    in  
                        CombinedData
        in 
            FinalResult,

    #"Data Endpoint" = #"DataEndpoint",
    AccessToken = GetAccessToken,
    #"Calls the functions and makes the result" = GetData(#"Data Endpoint" & "&acces_token=" & AccessToken)
in
    #"Calls the functions and makes the result"
```

Posting the answer here maybe it helps others too.